# I want to check whether the user session is set or not when i run this code it gives "page isn't working localhost redirected you too many times."

Tags: php, mysql, session, isset

I want to check whether the user session is set or not if the session is not set it redirects the user to the login page if the session is set it redirects the user to the view.php page but when I run this code it gives me this error "page isn't working localhost redirected you too many times."

```
    $uid=$_SESSION['uid'];

    if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])==false || isset($_SESSION['uid'])==$uid) 
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])==false)
        {
            header("Location:login.php");
        }
        if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])==$uid)
        {
            header("Location:view.php");
        }
    }
```

Comment: isset() returns a true or false value if a variable is set, not the value of what is or is not set. Also, it is bad practice (or not practiced at all) to send relative Header redirect requests like that, they should be absolute (http://www.example.com/login.php)

Comment: What @JohnSmith said... plus: you access $_SESSION['uid'] already before you make the check, if it even exists :) First check with isset(), and if it exists compare it to some value.

Comment: @HonkderHase what if i write like this without storing it in any variable?if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])==false || isset($_SESSION['uid'])==true) 
 {
  if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])==false)
  {
   header("Location:login.php");
  }
  if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])==true)
  {
   header("Location:view.php");
  }
 }

Comment: `if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) { /* redirect to view.php */ } else { /* redirect to login.php */ }`